# Eigenvalues of an amplification matrix

Tags: eigenvalues, eigenvector, linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ square real matrices.
I know that the matrix $A+B$ has 1 as eigenvalue of multiplicity 1 and the others eigenvalues have their modulus <1.
Can we say something about the eigenvalues of $exp(i\theta)A+B$ with $0\leq \theta < 2\pi$ ?
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You can't say much.  For example, let $A$ be any real diagonal matrix, and then pick a real diagonal matrix $B$ such that $A+B$ satisfies your property.  Then $uA+B=(u-1)A+(A+B)$, and so the triangle inequality gives
$$
|u-1|\|A\|_2-1
\leq\|uA+B\|_2
\leq|u-1|\|A\|_2+1.
$$
That is, the largest eigenvalue of $uA+B$ is on the order of the (unknown) largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C=A+B$ be any real matrix. Let $A$ be any real matrix, then $B=C-A$ is a real matrix. Then $e^{i\theta} A+ B = (e^{i\theta}-1) A + C$. Since $A$ can be any real matrix, this bears essentially no relationship to $C$!

About the only thing we can say is that the difference of the traces of $e^{i\theta} A +B$ and $A+B$ is $(1-e^{i\theta})$ times a real number. Since the trace of $A+B$ is a real number between $d$ and $2-d$, with $d$ the dimension of the matrices, this gives you a band of possible values for the trace of $e^{i\theta} A + B$.

Comment: Will - You have a -1 in the exponent, when it shouldn't be there.